# Lista desplegable dinámica en formulario de Google

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-forms

Tengo un Formulario de Google con *listas desplegables*, al cual le ingresé la información a mostrar en la *lista desplegable* por medio de una Hoja de Cálculo de Google.

Esto lo logré basándome en este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3AL7ASI_cA&t=809s

La siguiente parte, que no he logrado realizar y por lo cual solicito de su expertise, es que necesito que al seleccionar el

**NUMERO CONTROL** (del empleado) > **PLANTAS** (Donde trabaja ese empleado) > **MARCA DEL EQUIPO** (a revisar) >**NUMERO ECONOMICO** (del equipo a revisado)

```
var HojaCalculoDatos = SpreadsheetApp.openById(HojaCalculoID).getSheetByName("Datos");
var HojaCalculoMontacargas = SpreadsheetApp.openById(HojaCalculoID).getSheetByName("Montacargas");
var HojaCalculoFormularioEmpleados = SpreadsheetApp.openById(HojaCalculoID).getSheetByName("Formulario Empleados");
var Formulario = FormApp.openById(FormularioID);

//desplegar la informacion en el formulario
function main (){

  var etiquetas = HojaCalculoDatos.getRange(1, 1,1,HojaCalculoDatos.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  
  etiquetas.forEach(function(etiqueta,i){
    Logger.log(etiqueta,i);
    var opciones = HojaCalculoDatos.getRange(2, i+1, HojaCalculoDatos.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(o){ return o[0]})
    .filter(function (o){ return o !== ""});
    Logger.log(opciones);
    ActualizaListaDesplegableUsandoTitulo(etiqueta,opciones); 
  });
  
  
};

//actualizando la Lista desplegable por medio del titulo de la pregunta del formulario
function ActualizaListaDesplegableUsandoTitulo(titulo,valores) {
  
  var items = Formulario.getItems();
  var titulos = items.map(function(item){ 
    return item.getTitle();
    
  });
  
  var pos = titulos.indexOf(titulo);
  if (pos !==-1){
  var item  = items[pos];
  var itemID = item.getId();
  
  
  ActualizaListaDesplegable(itemID,valores);
  
  
  }
}


function ActualizaListaDesplegable(id,valores) {
  
  var item = Formulario.getItemById(id); 
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(valores);
  
}
```

Tengo una duda, será posible que esto se realice?
lo estoy planeando en preguntas diferentes (como en *listas desplegables* diferentes), ya que es información que es necesaria ingresar de nuevo en una base de datos ligada al formulario

De igual manera, necesito que me aparezca la información de forma ordenada, y no se como realizarlo.

Mi duda viene, a que caí en cuenta que al cargar el formulario, no se vuelve a hacer una "actualización" al momento de pasar a la siguiente sección.

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente clara al exponer mi idea y dudas.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente lo que estas buscando es tener listas desplegables dependientes en un formulario de Google

Esto no es posible.

Lo anterior porque los formularios de Google no tienen dicha característica y no es posible agregarla usando Google Apps Script ya que este sólo puede usarse para crear y modificar formularios, agregar un menú personalizado a la vista de editor de formulario, agregar un activador para cuando se envíe una respuesta pero no para añadir funcionalidades a la vista para responder de un formulario.

Una alternativa es que uses Google Apps Script para crear un aplicación web que funciones como un formulario.

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Saludos